# How do i get my python code to click mp3 download button from this site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to automate downloading mp3 versions of youtube video from this site: https://ytmp4converter.com/ using selenium but i have encountered some challenges can someone help.

Here is the code i have come up with so far, that falls short of clicking the download button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://ytmp4converter.com/")


#How to access elements on the page
#Id, name, class is the hierachical way of searching for specific element within HTML

search = driver.find_element("name", "url")
#Now what this will do is it will return to as an object that represents that search bar
#that we can actually interact with and mess around

search.send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQogzYUoQWU&list=RDBQogzYUoQWU&start_radio=1") #This sends input on the search bar e.g "test"
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #This is the computer version of pressing the "Enter" button

#/download.php?source=youtube&media=OA==
#link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "https://ytmp4converter.com/en/wp-content/plugins/aio-video-downloader/download.php?source=youtube&media=OA==")
#link.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "https://ytmp4converter.com/en/wp-content/plugins/aio-video-downloader/download.php?source=youtube&media=OA==" )))
element.click()
```

can someone show me i'm going wrong. This the error that i encounter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAMWEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\a3051e50-4690-11ed-bd2c-11f5bac330f8", line 34, in <module>
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "https://ytmp4converter.com/en/wp-content/plugins/aio-video-downloader/
    download.php?source=youtube&media=OA==" )))
  File "C:\Users\****** ******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages
  \selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x008BDF13+2219795]
    Ordinal0 [0x00852841+1779777]
    Ordinal0 [0x0076423D+803389]
    Ordinal0 [0x00793025+995365]
    Ordinal0 [0x007931EB+995819]
    Ordinal0 [0x007C0F52+1183570]
    Ordinal0 [0x007AE844+1108036]
    Ordinal0 [0x007BF192+1175954]
    Ordinal0 [0x007AE616+1107478]
    Ordinal0 [0x00787F89+950153]
    Ordinal0 [0x00788F56+954198]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB2CB2+3040210]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BA2BB4+2974420]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00956A0A+565546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00955680+560544]
    Ordinal0 [0x00859A5C+1808988]
    Ordinal0 [0x0085E3A8+1827752]
    Ordinal0 [0x0085E495+1827989]
    Ordinal0 [0x008680A4+1867940]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75E7FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E77A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E77A6E+238]
```

And here is the html code that surrounds that button.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slower but easier fix using the youtube_dl library.

Don't forget to `pip install youtube_dl`

```
import youtube_dl

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQogzYUoQWU'

video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
    url=video_url, download=False
)

filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"

options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'keepvideo': False,
    'outtmpl': filename,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])

print("Download complete... {}".format(filename))
```